# Problem with simple prime number function

Tags: python, primes

I am trying to make a function to check if a number is a prime number based on the result of a modulo operation; so far so good but it seems to classify 9 as a prime number for some reason.

```
def is_prime(x):
  if x <= 1: return False
  elif x == 2 or x == 3: return True
  else:
    for n in range(2, x - 1):
      if x % n == 0:
        return False
      else:
        return True
```

With that function if you run it as `is_prime(9)` it returns a `True` value, although if you type `9 % 3` on the interpreter it outputs `0`.

I guess I am making a mistake but I am not seeing it, could you help me out please?

This is what happens when you try to run it in the interpreter:

```
Python 3.11.2 (tags/v3.11.2:878ead1, Feb  7 2023, 16:38:35) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def is_prime(x):
...     for n in range(2, x-1):
...             if x % n == 0: return False
...             else: return True
... 
>>> is_prime(9)
True
```

But technically `n = 3` and `x = 9` used as `x % n` should output `0` right?

Comment: Your else clause is the problem. You shouldn’t return true there. You should return true after your for loop exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't `return true` in the `for loop`. You should wait until after your `for loop` finishes iterating through all the possibilities. The way you have it set up right now:

```
is_prime(9)
```

It will do `x % n` where `n` is 2 and returns `true` because `x % n` is not equal to 0. So your function should look like this:

```
def is_prime(x):
    for n in range(2, x-1):
            if x % n == 0: return False
    return True # Is prime
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason it's returning `True` for `9` is because when it gets to the loop it starts with 2 and checks `9%2 == 0` which is `False` so it goes to the else and returns `True`. you can fix this by changing your code to:

```py
def is_prime(x):
  return all(x % n != 0 for n in range(2, x-1))
```

here we are basically asking if all the numbers below the number don't divide it then the number is prime.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your implementation of the `is_prime` function. The issue is that the function `returns True` if the modulo operation with any value of `n` is not zero, rather than checking if the modulo operation is zero for all values of n from `2 to x-1.`

To fix this, you should move the `return True` statement outside the for loop, so it is only executed if the loop completes without finding a factor of `x`.

Here's correct implementation

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return False
    elif x == 2 or x == 3:
        return True
    else:
        for n in range(2, x):
            if x % n == 0:
                return False
        return True # Moved outside for loop


Output: is_prime(9)
False
```